# Optional<String> to Int64 is nil, hardcoded it works

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function:

```
func setId(id: Int64?) {
    self._id = id
}
```

This function is called here:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let id = defaults.object(forKey: "userId") as? String
if (id != nil) {
    setId(id: Int64(id!))
}
```

In the function `setId()` the value of `id` always seems to be nil. When debugging and stepping one call up in the stack, to the caller (2nd piece of code) the value of `id` is

`po id`:

```
Optional<String>
  - some : "Optional(350350002)"
```

When I check it as `Int64`:

`po Int64(id!)`:
`nil`

When I check it with a hardcoded value:

`po Int64(Optional("350350002")!)`:

```
Optional<Int64>
  - some : 350350002
```

Also `po Int64((id as NSString))`: `nil`

What is going on here? How does the hardcoded value differ from the actual variable?

Thanks.

Comment: The issue is that you are saving the `String` containing the `Optional` word itself. You need to make sure that you save the (safely) unwrapped version instead of the optional one to get rid of the `Optional` keyword in the String. Btw you should never do a `nil`-check for an Optional then force-unwrap the value. Use Optional-binding instead to safely unwrap the value.

Comment: Why is `_id` optional at all? Are there really users without `id`? And why don't you save the integer rather than a string in `UserDefaults`. And why `Int64`? Are you expecting more than 4 billion users? By the way there is a `string(forKey` method and for integers even an `integer(forKey` method which **never** returns an optional.

Comment: In other words, the saved value is invalid. You need to show us the code that is saving the value. Also, it does not make sense converting numbers to strings before saving.

Comment: @DávidPásztor you are correct! It was saving the word 'Optional' with it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the following was saved to UserDefaults: `String(describing: self._userId)`, of course saving the actual word 'Optional(...' with it, as String.

I thought the debugger was showing me an Optional with value 350350002 instead of an actual string: "Optional(350350002)" + the saving to UserDefaults code was not written by me, why I didn't notice this.

Comment: That’s why one should *never* use String(describing:) instead of the normal String() initializer. :)